# How to run task in x-time (Minute and Hour)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Trying to write a small app which need to run a task at x-minutes or x-hour.
What I'm facing is the way to calculate the x-time in order to run the task at the specified minute or hour.

My app is just simple : one listbox for minutes (1 to 59), and a textbox to input the message to display at the specified time.
so when the user select like 50 min, and enter "Hello", the program after 50 minutes, it has to display a messagebox with "Hello" message, and should have multithread to avoid Ui blockade when running one task, another should also be run.

I tried to use For... Loop to count each second, but I'm not getting the expected result.

```html
Dim s as string

For Each s in myVariable
    console.writeLine("Message")
Next
```

Comment: [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) would save you some time!

Comment: How many Timer should I put?? as the number of task is not known. and how do i handle it?

Comment: If you could atleast go through the documentation, you would get a general idea. Moreover google about Timer to get examples related to the same

Comment: @Nobody : Pun intended? ;)

Comment: @VisualVincent damn, that is what missing from it. Guess you got my back there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Thread.Sleep(milliseconds)` to achieve what you want

```html
Dim s as string = "Hi"

Thread.Sleep(1000)
console.writeLine("Message")
```

It must be done in a new Thread

Reference at https://www.dotnetperls.com/sleep-vbnet

Or you can use a `Timer`:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Timers

Public Class TimerTest
     Shared _timer As Timer
     Shared _list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Start the timer.
    ''' </summary>
    Shared Sub Start()
        _timer = New Timer(3000)
        AddHandler _timer.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf Handler)
        _timer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get timer output.
    ''' </summary>
    Shared Function GetOutput() As String
        Return String.Join("<br>", _list)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Timer event handler.
    ''' </summary>
    Shared Sub Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        _list.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Example from https://www.dotnetperls.com/timer-vbnet

You create one timer per click of the button and you're done :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorry for the delay as I was away.

Answer (score 1):

If program should display message after selected amount of minutes, then you can use asynchronous approach.

```
' When combobox value changed
Private Async Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim comboBox = DirectCase(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim minutesAmount = DirectCast(comboBox.SelectedItem, Integer)

    await Task.Delay(minutesAmount * 60000) 

    MessageBox.Show("Hello")
End Sub
```

`Task.Delay` will wait until given amount of milliseconds is elapsed and continue execution to next line.
`await Task.Delay` will not block UI thread